# Throw an exception displaying parameters passed into a void method in Java 8 Mockito

Tags: java, java-8, mockito

I have a test suite using Mockito that mocks certain void functions to `doNothing()` if passed the correct parameters and to throw an error if passed wrong ones. When it detects incorrect parameters I want it to also print the parameters it received in the exception it throws.

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception(String.format("Failed step 1. Received parameters: %s, %s", param1, param2)))
        .when(factory).load(any(), any());
Mockito.doNothing().when(factory).load(eq("correct"), eq("correct"));
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this because Additional Answers does not apply to void return types. This needs to work for Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `doAnswer` in order to print the parameters the way you're expecting. It will allow you to access the parameters of the mocked method by using `getArgument(int i)` method.

```
Mockito.doAnswer(i -> {
            throw new Exception(String.format("Failed step 1. Received parameters: %s, %s", i.getArgument(0), i.getArgument(1)));
                })
                .when(factory).load(any(), any());
Mockito.doNothing().when(factory).load(eq("correct"), eq("correct"));
```

Answer (score 0):

While CaptainAye's solution is a great one, I realized I could do what I was looking for in a lot less code by using `Mockito.verify`.

```
Mockito.verify(factory).load(eq("correct"), eq("correct"));
```